# How to authenticate using Azure Active Directory to connect with azure sql using pymssql?

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, pymssql

I am trying to access azure sql instance from airflow and for that I am using pymssql library and active directory authentication. Here is the sample code for the same to establish the connection.

```
pymssql.connect("MyHostname", "user@xyz.com", "Password", "DbName")
```

This process is leading me to the below mentioned error.

```
40532, 'Cannot open server 'xyz.com' requested by the login. The login failed.DB-Lib error message 20018.
```

Can anyone please suggest me what am I doing wrong here and is there any alternative for the same?